# glDrawArrays doesn't draw

Tags: c++, opengl

I use vectors to store vertex and normal data

```
vector<float> vertex;
vector<float> normal;
```

For example:

```
normal.push_back(-1);
normal.push_back(0);
normal.push_back(0);

vertex.push_back(BARRIER_RADIUS);
vertex.push_back(POLE_HEIGHT);
vertex.push_back(-POLE_RADIUS);

for (int i = POLE_POINTS, i >= 0; i--)
{
    //add more vertex
}

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertex[0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &normal[0]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertex.size());

glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
//Add some more + Draw some thing else the same way
```

What I've got from this is nothing. it doesn't draw anything onto the screen.

The previous version, which works, is as follow:

```
glNormal3f(-1, 0, 0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex3f(BARRIER_RADIUS, POLE_HEIGHT, -POLE_RADIUS);
    for ()
    { 
        //add more vertex
        glVertex3f(........);
    }
glEnd();

//draw more the same way
```

Point me to where I've gone wrong.

Comment: There are a lot of things in the pipeline that could go wrong. The data, the rendering calls, the shaders etc. Are you sure that the problem is in the code you posted?

Comment: It's the only part that I can think of.

Comment: There are definitely more parts. What window manager do you use? How do you init your data? When do you call your rendering functions? How do you read and build your shaders? How do the shaders look? Do you use shaders at all?

Comment: I dont have a shader at all. all the data I need is a vector of vertex and a vector of normal as shown above. That's pretty much all to it. This is the function that doesn't display. I have 2 other objects, which are drawn perfectly using VBO. In those cases, I have objects to load. In this case, I don't, I have to specify vertex and normal myself.

Comment: Try a calling GLenum error = glGetError() before and after your rendering calls and see if the variable error is anything other than GL_NO_ERROR.

Comment: by rendering calls, do you mean the glDrawArray?

Comment: Yeah, for example. The reason for doing one before as well as after is to reset any previous errors. You could also just start at the very end and if there is an error there, work your way up.

Comment: if so, then it returns GL_NO_ERROR.

Comment: Alright. Then the OpenGL state is correct, and I can't see anything wrong with your code. Did you change anything else in your code when changing from using glVertex3f etc?

Comment: What are the possible reasons for an object not to show up? does it have anything to do with the normal? because the number of normals, in comparison to those of vertex, is really small. I can't tell exactly though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `vertex` as a vector of `float`, but a geometric vertex consists of 3 floats, so that's a recipe for confusion.  The number of vertices is not `vertex.size()`, but rather one third of that.  I'm not sure if that's your only problem, but it's a problem.

You should have the same number of normals as vertices.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed it. However, it is not the problem. :( same number of normals as vertices? but in the glVertex3f version above, all I have 1 glNormal3f(-1, 0, 0) and a loop containing glVertex3f. so they are not equals, are they? I'm confused.

Comment: @ThangDo *"I'm confused"* - You're not the only one (didn't get this comment at all). The problem is you have to decide what `vertex` and `normal` contain. From your code it looks like they contain individual floats, therefore 3 consecutive values make a single vertex. But in this case you have to draw only `vertex.size()/3` vertices (in the call to `glDrawArrays`). Another option might be to let `vertex` and `normal` contain actual 3-element vectors (arrays or POD structs, not `std::vector`s, by any means *not* `std::vector`s!) and then you would indeed have `vertex.size()` vertices.

Comment: @ThangDo And when you draw something with `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` you indeed *have* to have the same number of normal as you have positions (if that's what your above comment is about). This `glBegin/glEnd`-combine-as-you-like madness won't work anymore.

Comment: @ThangDo *"Yes, I have noticed it. However, it is not the problem."* - How do you know that, because it *definitely* is *a* problem at least.

Comment: @ChristianRau I'm sorry. It was in fact the problem. I made a mistake in specify the size of the buffer. It should have been the size in bytes. What I had was the number of item in vertex vector. You are definitely right. cheers. I have got it to display perfectly now.

Comment: @ThangDo Huh? There are no buffers (if you mean GL buffer objects) in your posted code at all (or anything else where the size in bytes could be needed).

Comment: If you do want to use the same normal for all vertices, I think you could do it by not enabling a normal array, and not calling `glNormalPointer`, but going back to `glNormal3f`.